# mongodb-go-driver/bson struct to bson.Document encoding

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mongo-go

I'm working with https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver and
currently trying to implement a partial update of such struct

```
type NoteUpdate struct {
    ID        string `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Title     string `json:"title" bson:"title,omitempty"`
    Content   string `json:"content" bson:"content,omitempty"`
    ChangedAt int64  `json:"changed_at" bson:"changed_at"`
}
```

For instance, if I have

```
noteUpdate := NoteUpdate{ Title: "New Title" }
```

Then I expect that the only "title" field in the stored document will be changed.

I need to write something like

```
collection.FindOneAndUpdate(context.Background(),
    bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.String("_id", noteUpdate.ID)),
    // I need to encode non-empty fields here
    bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.SubDocument("$set", bson.NewDocument(...)))
)
```

The problem is that I don't want to manually encode each non-empty field with `bson.EC.String(...)` or `bson.EC.Int64(...)`. I tried to use `bson.EC.InterfaceErr(...)` but got an error

> Cannot create element for type *models.NoteUpdate, try using bsoncodec.ConstructElementErr

Unfortunately, there is no such function in bsoncodec. The only way I found is to create wrapper

```
type SetWrapper struct {
    Set interface{} `bson:"$set,omitempty"`
}
```

And use it like

```
partialUpdate := &NoteUpdate{
    ID: "some-note-id", 
    Title: "Some new title",
 }
updateParam := SetWrapper{Set: partialUpdate}
collection.FindOneAndUpdate(
    context.Background(),
    bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.String("_id", noteUpdate.ID)),
    updateParam,
)
```

It works, but is it possible to achieve the same with bson/bsoncodec document builders ?

UPD. The full context of my question:
I wrote the REST endpoint for **partially** updating "Note" documents(stored in MongoDB). Code that I have now:

```
var noteUpdate models.NoteUpdate
ctx.BindJSON(&noteUpdate)    
//omit validation and errors handling
updateParams := services.SetWrapper{Set: noteUpdate}
res := collection.FindOneAndUpdate(
context.Background(),
bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.String("_id", noteUpdate.ID)),
    updateParams,
    findopt.OptReturnDocument(option.After),
)
```

Code that I want to have

```
var noteUpdate models.NoteUpdate
ctx.BindJSON(&noteUpdate)    
//omit validation and errors handling
res := collection.FindOneAndUpdate(
    context.Background(),
    bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.String("_id", noteUpdate.ID)),
    bson.NewDocument(
        //bsoncodec.ConstructElement doesn't exists
        bsoncodec.ConstructElement("$set", &noteUpdate)),
        ),
    findopt.OptReturnDocument(option.After),
)
```

Code that I **don't** want to have

```
var noteUpdate models.NoteUpdate
ctx.BindJSON(&noteUpdate)
//omit validation and errors handling
bsonNote := bson.NewDocument()
if noteUpdate.Title != "" {
    bsonNote.Append(bson.EC.String("title", noteUpdate.Title))
}
if noteUpdate.Content != "" {
    bsonNote.Append(bson.EC.String("content", noteUpdate.Content))
}
//..setting the rest of the fields...
res := collection.FindOneAndUpdate(
    context.Background(),
    bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.String("_id", noteUpdate.ID)),
    bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.SubDocument("$set", bsonNote)),
    findopt.OptReturnDocument(option.After),
)
```

So, the precise question is - is there any way to build *bson.Document dynamically based on `bson` tags(without predefined wrappers like my SetWrapper)?

Comment: *"The problem is that I don't want to manually encode each non-empty field"* - Could you please give some more context in your question of what exactly you mean by this. `$set` operations only ever touch the fields **explicitly** named under them. "Omitting" the `$set` altogether effectively "overwrites" the entire existing document with only specified properties. Modern API even breaks this up with a `*Replace*` variant that specifically prohibits the usage of `$set` and other atomic operators in this context for the sake of code clarity. An example of what you expect would be clearer

Comment: @NeilLunn I added the example of what I expect from the `$set` operation. I only want to update some fields of the stored document, not to replace it entirely.

Comment: What you added does not really explain anything. Instead of saying "I want something **like**", show the code you **actually attempted to use** and then show the problem with it. All you show right now is `$set", bson.NewDocument(...)` and it's the `...` part you are omitting that actually seems to be the actual important part of the question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately this is currently not supported.

You may create a helper function which "converts" a struct value to a [`bson.D`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson#D) like this:

```
func toDoc(v interface{}) (doc *bson.D, err error) {
    data, err := bson.Marshal(v)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    err = bson.Unmarshal(data, &doc)
    return
}
```

Then it can be used like this:

```
partialUpdate := &NoteUpdate{
    Title: "Some new title",
}

doc, err := toDoc(partialUpdate)
// check error

res := c.FindOneAndUpdate(
    context.Background(),
    bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.String("_id", "some-note-id")),
    bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.SubDocument("$set", doc)),
)
```

Hopefully [`ElementConstructor.Interface()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson#ElementConstructor.Interface) will improve in the future and allow passing struct values or pointers to struct values directly.